# Detecting scrolling position within a scrollable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

we usually use `$(window).scrollTop()` to detect how far the page has been scrolled. Is there a equivalent for scrollable elements?

Say I set html to overflow hidden, and body to overflow scroll, now I want to detect `$('body').scrollTop()` I will always get 0.

P.S. this is useful for mobile site development.

Here is a plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/jZH3zCiMSfk5bIZIoDEp/

Comment: elm.scrollTop is a property of every element

Comment: what are you trying to do? Very rare to ever get body scrolling unless set height  and overflow hidden on `<html>` which isn't common

Comment: @charlietfl To eliminate using fixed position because it causes issue across angular material framework.

Comment: Could it be a XY problem?  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem  Instead i guess you'd have better to ask question regarding your `issue across angular material framework`

Comment: @A.Wolff it is not. Angular only targets the body as its rootscope when calculating ripple effect. Once a page is been scrolled, the element will not apply ripple correctly. The page must be a single view.

Comment: Please provide example code that replicates problem

Comment: html alone is worthless without css and a question needs a proper problem statement and expected results. Suggest you create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common issue with Angular. Instead of making the body scrollable, you should wrap everything inside a div and make the div an Angular controller. Then use the `ng-scroll` to detect scrolling position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get top offset of an element.

Like so with jQuery

```
  $('body').offset().top
```

Comment: Not quite. I tried this too, and it also returns 0. This is because the offset to top, which is the html, is always 0.